# Calling Function upon field change in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a entity called WorkOrder which gets assigned to an Employee.

I want send an email notification when the workorder has been asigned.  This can happen on my MVC Create or Edit Action (POST).

The problem i have is i have to do checks to see if the value has changed in the Edit to determine if i should send an email.

Is there a better place to call the SendEmail Function, like in the Entity Model itself?

Comment: I'd personally call the function in the controller, `if (originalWorkOrder != postedWorkOrder) { sendWorkOrderEmail(postedWorkOrder);}`

Comment: The Entity model should contain the rule if that Entity is used in other systems where that rule should also be applied if the same conditions are met, otherwise I'd put it in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about posting from a view, you could create and bind the existing value to a hidden field in your form when loading the view. Then, on the POST to your action you can check to see if the value from the field is different from the one that is on the hidden field.

**Example of View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController")
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentValue)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value)
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

**Example of Action GET**

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var viewModel = GetModelFromSomeWhere();
    viewModel.CurrentValue = viewModel.Value;
    return this.View(viewModel);
}
```

**Example of Action POST**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(ViewModel model)
{
    if (model.Value != model.CurrentValue)
    {
        // It has changed! Send that email!
    }
}
```